# Saddle valve problem

Tags: basement

My humidifier is supplied from a saddle valve.   I don't think that there is much flow to the humidifier. What is the best way to rectify this problem

Comment: Can you get us photos of this? Also, what makes you believe that it's a flow issue?

Comment: I have flow, I have plenty of supply pressure, however with the control cranked to 85%, my hygrometer reads 38% humidity.  This is a whole house unit which is running in conjunction with my forced hot air furnace. I realize that the outside humidity is very low.

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you the same advice I give everybody about saddle valves... **Replace it** with a proper tee.

- Turn off the water.
- Drain the line.
- Cut the line so the tee will fit in.
- Install the tee.
- Install a shutoff on the leg of the tee feeding the humidifier.
- Install the pipe that feeds humidifier.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I thought saddle valves are not allowed by most plumbing codes. They are prone to clogging.

It is probably scaled up. Do you have water in the holding tank of the humidifier?

Close the valve all the way and remove the connector at the humidifier. Put the end into a bucket and open the valve to see if you get flow. If not the valve could be scaled over inside the pipe it is saddling.

If it is scaled up you will have to shut off the main line and remove the valve and clean it or replace it. Better yet install a proper valve in the main line to feed your humidifier.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I did that plenty of flow to the humidifier, no holding tank. Sprays into the discharge of secondary plenum

Answer (score 0):

cut out a 3/4" spot where the valve used to be. use a 1/2 x 1/2 x 1/4" tee push fit valve. use sand paper to clean cut sides of pipe. push each side into copper tubing. reconnect a plastic line or use a 1/4" braided reconnect to humidifier. Go sit and drink beer.

Comment: Installing a shutoff valve after the tee, gives you the benefit of being able to turn off the water to the humidifier. In case you ever have to work on, or replace the unit.